# DOES this App use the Advertising identifier (IDFA)?

Tags: ios, iphone

I have uploaded my iOS a few days ago. now I am getting this message

Does this app use the Advertising Identifier (IDFA)?
The Advertising Identifier (IDFA) is a unique ID for each iOS device and is the only way to offer targeted ads. Users can choose to limit ad targeting on their iOS device.

Yes

No
Ensure that you select the correct answer for Advertising Identifier (IDFA) usage. If your app does contain the IDFA and you select No, the binary will be permanently rejected and you will have to submit a different binary.

my App does not contain any ads but it shows HTML pages on click on buttons.
should I select yes or no?

Comment: are you used the adsupport framework or else any admob used in your app

Comment: no i didn't use this

Comment: then simple , select NO

Comment: thanks @Anbu.Karthik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not showing ads but it shows HTML pages.

So if you are not using IDFA, you should also select it as NO.

Answer (score 2):

I have develop an app which is live on **App Store**. It is not showing ads but it shows HTML pages same as in your scenario. I always select it as NO.

So if you are not using IDFA, you should also select it as **NO**.